# Postgres B-Tree order and height

Tags: postgresql, indexing, b-tree

Is there a way to find the order of B-Tree used for the specific index in Postgres? And the actual height as well?

Is the order supposed to be fixed or rather dependent on size of the index fields (to fit the page size)?

Sort of ambiguous, the order is sometimes referred to a maximum number of children of the node, sometimes to a minimum number (for non-root node). But it's interesting either way.

Comment: I don't have the answer, the manual might have it: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens, sure, I've read the manual. But it does not seem to have such details.

Comment: "*New leaf pages are added to a B-Tree index when an existing leaf page cannot fit an incoming tuple.*" sounds very much like it's size-dependent

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense. A B-tree is always totally ordered. The depth varies with the size of the index entries, the number of table rows and the leaf density. Perhaps you should read up some basics about B-trees, then you can ask a meaningful question.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe It's just a confusing terminology: "*A B-tree of **order** `m` is a search tree in which each nonleaf node has up to `m` children.*" ([source](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs3110/2012sp/recitations/rec25-B-trees/rec25.html)) And to further increase confusion, [some authors mean the minimum number whereas others mean the maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree#Differences_in_terminology).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know of no place where you can see that information at a single glance, but you can use the [B-tree functions of the “pageinspect” extension](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pageinspect.html#id-1.11.7.32.6) for that: `bt_metap()` will point you to the root node, and `bt_page_stats()` for the root node will show you the level `btpo_level`. By using `bt_page_items()` on a couple of index pages, you can see how many children each has.